# vscode is opening an external terminal by default

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm have been using VSCode terminal on Windows 10. After last week's update, I would do the same ctrl + ` shortcut to open the terminal via VSCode. I would type npm start, however, this time it opened an external terminal. How do I change the configurations so it would not open externally?

Thanks

Comment: I'm using a clean v1.67 (insiders) and I get the integrated terminal, maybe remove your settings and try again - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: Answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71937880/vscode-how-to-disable-the-npm-auto-update-pop-up-window/71957691#71957691

Comment: HI, in your settings (Keyboard Shortcuts), what are the values associated with `Open New External Terminal`, `Terminal: Create New Terminal` and `View: Toggle Terminal`?