# VSCode: How to disable the npm auto-update pop up window

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, auto-update

A command-line window started to pop up occasionally recently:
[image: The command-line pop up window]
Usually, it flashed across the screen so quickly that I could not capture its appearance. It took me a while to get this screenshot.
According to the title, it seems to be launched from some auto-update service related to npm.
Considering that **I've recently updated Visual Studio Code**, and **it often appears when I open Visual Studio Code**, the conclusion that it's caused by Visual Studio Code is my conjecture.
It's quite annoying and I'm trying to figure out a way to disable it. Had anyone faced the same problem and knew how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the same issue. Wait 2 minutes after opening a project, a terminal window will open and execute this command

npm install @hint/configuration-development@latest hint@latest typescript@latest

[image]

After disabling VSCode extensions one-by-one, the issue disappears with

**Microsoft Edge Tools for VS Code extension**
Marketplace Info
Released on
6/21/2019, 15:42:07
Last updated
4/5/2022, 18:45:15
Identifier
ms-edgedevtools.vscode-edge-devtools

The issue appears to be addressed by the extension developer, but no remarks are provided.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-edge-devtools/issues/980

Comment: Thanks! I guess that's exactly the problem. It's now being tracked in [#976](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-edge-devtools/issues/976), and the team is already working on it.